# Creating Centroid Long and Lat points for each Kernel Density cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, kernel-density

I am trying to create a point raster file of the highest (red) kernel densities (figure 1), which places one GPS location at the centre of each of the cells within the highest kernel density bins.

I have tried to merge my kernel into a mosaic raster but this loses data and is continuous, which for further analysis in maxent I need discreet values.

I have also tried converting the kernel plots to point raster but this creates the entire extent of my study site and not my highest kernel bin, as suggested in http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_way_in_ArcGIS_to_calculate_the_Latitude_and_Longitude_of_each_pixel.

Are there any tools i have overlooked which address this?

Forgive me if they are obvious. ARC GIS 10.1

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the red areas are a single value? If so you could:

1. [Extract by attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_by_Attributes/009z00000029000000/).
2. [Convert to polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/).
3. Finally extract the [centroid](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Feature_To_Point/00170000003m000000/).
4. Optionally extract the [coordinates of the points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_XY_Coordinates/001700000032000000/).

If you were going to do this on many datasets you could easily wrap this workflow up in a fairly simple model.

Comment: This is very helpful and is nearly what I need, but I was thinking more along the lines of one GPS location for each cell with the kernel density (ie 1km2 x 20 cells). Maybe a grid from the polygons that were just create to point would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hornbydd,

I adapted your method. What i did was

1.Firstly i created a point raster file for my entire extent of my map as suggested by "http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_way_in_ArcGIS_to_calculate_the_Latitude_and_Longitude_of_each_pixel." and set the point to be 1km2 apart.

2.Reclassified the kernel density models

3.extracted by attribute ("value">3), This was representative of my highest kernel (Red)

4.Then converted to polygon (raster to polygon tool)

5. Then i clipped the highest kernel polygon to step one, this created a series of 1km2 points within the kernel
6. Then I added xy coordinates (add xy coordinates)
7. Then extracted the table as a .txt file, and changed it to .csv

8.Imported this into MAxent